# Wamp 5.3.21 on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, php, wamp

I want to install PHP version 5.3.21 on my windows 7 64 bit machine.

I am able to locate the binaries for [32bit](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/) version but not the 64 bit versions

1. Does WAMP 32 bit work on a 64 bit machine like XAMPP does ?
2. I tried compiling from source. What options should I mention in configure to get a standard php install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that WAMP 32 bit works on a 64 bit machine

Answer (score 0):

Only x86 binaries are available from the official PHP.net website for PHP 5.3.21. To build the x64 binary from source, the source code should also be programmed for 64-bit. For now, you can install x64 binary for the latest version of PHP.

Comment: I need php 5.3.21 to test the backward compatibility of an application and hence do not want the latest version

Comment: 32bit binaries of PHP will also work in 64bit Windows 7. So, you can go with 32bit version of PHP too.